# convert sybase trigger to mssql trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

I was tasked to migrate ASA to MSSQL database however I am not familiar with MSSQL trigger, can somebody convert this to MSSQL trigger?

```
COMMENT TO PRESERVE FORMAT ON TRIGGER "DBA"."BATCH_DEDUCTIONS"."deductions_update" IS 
{create TRIGGER deductions_update AFTER UPDATE OF "FACTOR", "RATE"
ORDER 1 ON "DBA"."BATCH_DEDUCTIONS"
REFERENCING OLD AS old_row NEW AS new_row
FOR EACH ROW /* WHEN( search_condition ) */
BEGIN
    /* Type the trigger statements here */
    declare trfactor numeric(12,6);
    declare trrate numeric(12,6);
    declare tramount numeric(12,2);
    set trfactor = new_row.factor;
    set trrate = new_row.rate;
    set tramount = trfactor * trrate;
    update "dba"."batch_deductions" set amount = tramount 
        where batchno = new_row.batchno and empid = new_row.empid and item_no = new_row.item_no 
              and itemcode = new_row.itemcode
END
}
go
```

Comment: Show your attempt. Where do you stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Please see the code below
--Hope it can help you..
;

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[deductions_update] 
   ON  [dbo].[BATCH_DEDUCTIONS] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
declare @tramount numeric(12,2);

select @tramount = (new_row.factor * new_row.rate) from inserted new_row

IF (UPDATE(factor) OR UPDATE(rate))
BEGIN
    update batch_deductions set amount = @tramount
    from batch_deductions, inserted new_row 
    where batch_deductions.batchno = new_row.batchno and batch_deductions.empid = new_row.empid and batch_deductions.item_no = new_row.item_no 
          and batch_deductions.itemcode = new_row.itemcode
END

-- Insert statements for trigger here
```

END

GO

Comment: Please when posting a code snippet, also explaining what it actually does. It's better than just hoping that smth helps.